# DART user Agent detection

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, dart

I want to detect the user agent at which my app is running,mainly I want to see if it is running as:

1. Chrome packaged app,
2. Chrome browser page,
3. Android webView
4. Firefox

I run this code, as starting:

```
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
print(ua);
```

and got this output line

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.76 (Dart) Safari/537.36
```

but actually I run it using DARTIUM, and have Chrome/FireFox/IE11

any thought!

Comment: This is expected. You should read up on [user agent strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent).

Comment: I didn't use it myself yet but https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/browser_detect might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/dart/+/master/dart/sdk/lib/html/html_common/device.dart

```
/**
 * Utils for device detection.
 */
class Device {
  static bool _isOpera;
  static bool _isIE;
  static bool _isFirefox;
  static bool _isWebKit;
  static String _cachedCssPrefix;
  static String _cachedPropertyPrefix;
  /**
   * Gets the browser's user agent. Using this function allows tests to inject
   * the user agent.
 * Returns the user agent.
   */
  static String get userAgent => window.navigator.userAgent;
  /**
   * Determines if the current device is running Opera.
   */
  static bool get isOpera {
    if (_isOpera == null) {
      _isOpera = userAgent.contains("Opera", 0);
    }
    return _isOpera;
  }
  /**
   * Determines if the current device is running Internet Explorer.
   */
  static bool get isIE {
    if (_isIE == null) {
      _isIE = !isOpera && userAgent.contains("Trident/", 0);
    }
    return _isIE;
  }
  /**
   * Determines if the current device is running Firefox.
   */
  static bool get isFirefox {
    if (_isFirefox == null) {
      _isFirefox = userAgent.contains("Firefox", 0);
    }
    return _isFirefox;
  }
  /**
   * Determines if the current device is running WebKit.
   */
  static bool get isWebKit {
    if (_isWebKit == null) {
      _isWebKit = !isOpera && userAgent.contains("WebKit", 0);
    }
    return _isWebKit;
  }
  /**
   * Gets the CSS property prefix for the current platform.
   */
  static String get cssPrefix {
    String prefix = _cachedCssPrefix;
    if (prefix != null) return prefix;
    if (isFirefox) {
      prefix = '-moz-';
    } else if (isIE) {
      prefix = '-ms-';
    } else if (isOpera) {
      prefix = '-o-';
    } else {
      prefix = '-webkit-';
    }
    return _cachedCssPrefix = prefix;
  }
  /**
   * Prefix as used for JS property names.
   */
  static String get propertyPrefix {
    String prefix = _cachedPropertyPrefix;
    if (prefix != null) return prefix;
    if (isFirefox) {
      prefix = 'moz';
    } else if (isIE) {
      prefix = 'ms';
    } else if (isOpera) {
      prefix = 'o';
    } else {
      prefix = 'webkit';
    }
    return _cachedPropertyPrefix = prefix;
  }
  /**
   * Checks to see if the event class is supported by the current platform.
   */
  static bool isEventTypeSupported(String eventType) {
    // Browsers throw for unsupported event names.
    try {
      var e = new Event.eventType(eventType, '');
      return e is Event;
    } catch (_) { }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Dartium identifies itself as Chrome, but contains '(Dart)' in the user-agent.

You can tell if your code is running as a chrome extension/app by checking for `chrome.runtime.id`, eg:

```dart
// You'll likely need to reference this package:
//   https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/chrome
if (window.chrome && window.chrome.runtime && window.chrome.runtime.id) {
  window.alert('App!');
}
```

If you're in control of the Android app, you can use `setUserAgentString` to tweak the user-agent, so you can then respond to it in your web app:

```dart
myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString('Danny/1.0 not Chrome or IE or Webkit');
```

The other browsers should be relatively easy using their user-agent strings.

Comment: Can u pls add little details about setUserAgentString for Android . is it in Manifest or in my app! Thanks

Comment: @HasanAYousef See edit; you just call `getSettings().setUserAgentString('blah');` on the web view.